# How can I get session id from api in React?

Tags: reactjs, session, token

I'm using React and axios.

Api gave me session id in header.
[X-Auth-Token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4avF.jpg)

X-Auth-Token is the token with session Id.

I have to take it and retrieve it. But I am having difficulty in even accessing token.

```
const login = async () => {
const { errorField, errorMessage } = validateLoginInput(loginInputs);
setErrorField(errorField);
setValidationMessage(errorMessage);
if (!errorMessage) {
  const response = await axios.post(
    "http://3.36.78.249/auth/sign-in",
    loginInputs,
    { withCredentials: true }
  );
  if (response.status === 400) {
    setErrorField({ email: true, password: true });
    setValidationMessage(validateErrorMessage.loginFailed);
  } else {
    setIsAuthenticated(true);
  }
  console.log(response);
  console.log(response.headers);
  return response;
}
```

};

This is my React Code. How can I get session Id from the header?

Comment: What do your `console.log` statements at the end of that code reveal?  Is the header present there?

Comment: No.. there's undefined. I just tried to access session Id in Token